# wp_update_comment() loses html-tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, comments

I've done a customized comment form for a Wordpress website and there is a possibility for users to add comments. I managed to allow more html-tags to these comments than the default ones. The tags work just fine when a new comment is posted, but when the comment is updated it loses all of these additionally allowed tags.

For updating the comment, I'm using wp_update_comment() -method. I searched a bit, but didn't find a solution yet. I'm passing comment's ID and comment's content as arguments for the method.

So what I'm basically asking is, can I use this method to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or should I delete the comment and create a new one in it's place?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `wp_update_comment()` calls `wp_filter_comment` function, and that one filters the content using the `pre_comment_content` filter. WP plugs the `wp_filter_kses` function to this filter, so using

```
remove_filter('pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_kses');
```

before calling `wp_update_comment()` should solve your problem. Just remember that you do have to filter the sent comment somehow to avoid security problems, ok?

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. I'll filter the comment some other way to prevent the security issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for [wp_update_comment()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_comment/#source-code) it looks like it cleans the comment up before updating the database. You may have to write your own function for this to get around it.